# Алгоритм парсинга строки для нахождения определенного поля и его значения

Tags: c++, строки, парсер

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Client client;
    client.setAddr("192.168.0.16");
    client.setPass("testPassword");
    client.setName("testHostName");

    if (client.init()) {
        std::string cpuInfo = client.getCpuInfo();
        // Do something ...

        client.term();
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Значение `cpuInfo`:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               1
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             2482.474
CPU max MHz:         3200.0000
CPU min MHz:         1550.0000
BogoMIPS:            6387.25
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11
```

После получения информации о процессоре, мне нужно будет сохранить ее по частям в базу данных.
И тут появляется проблема.

Какой вариант является самым быстрым и удобным, для парсинга строки. То и есть, если я хочу получить значения поля `CPU MHz`, как мне лучше всего получить это значение. Известно, что колонки слева - константные.

Первоначально, у меня было что то подобное:

```
std::istringstream stream(cpuInfo);
std::string word;
while (stream >> word) {
    if (word == "CPU") {
        stream >> word;
        if (word == "MHz") {
            std::string res;
            stream >> res;
            // Do something ...
        }
    }
}
```

Но я уверен, что это не самое лучшее решение, да и для парсинга всех полей, займет очень много времени и места.

Comment: А этот Client  не может предоставить информацию не в виде строки?

Comment: Можно сплит по `:` сделать

Comment: Читайте по строкам. В каждой строке ищете `':'` и используете текст от начала до двоеточия как ключ. Ищете этот ключ в ранее заведенном `map` с интересующей  информацией. Если нашли, то в зависимости от ее природы считываете данные после двоеточия. / что касается времени и памяти, то содержимое `/proc/cpuinfo` не столь велико, чтобы всерьез думать о производительности данной части кода

Comment: @user7860670 Нет. Он лишь может предоставить всю информацию о процессоре в виде строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать [std::regex_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) чтобы спарсить все поля/значения и поместить их в словарь типа [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <regex>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const auto cpu_info = string(R"__(Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
Address sizes:       43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               1
Model name:          AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             2482.474
CPU max MHz:         3200.0000
CPU min MHz:         1550.0000
BogoMIPS:            6387.25
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11
)__");

    const auto re = regex(R"__(^([^:]+):\s*([^\r\n]+)$)__");

    auto data = unordered_map<string, string>();

    transform(sregex_iterator(begin(cpu_info), end(cpu_info), re),
              sregex_iterator(),
              inserter(data, end(data)),
              [](const sregex_iterator::value_type& m) -> pair<string, string> {
                cout << "parsed '" << m[1].str() << "' = '" << m[2].str() << "'\n";
                return make_pair(m[1].str(), m[2].str());
              });

    cout << "CPU MHz = " << data["CPU MHz"] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если написать свой [insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator), то можно сохранять значения сразу в БД.

Comment: Круто. Но на мой вкус -- unsupportable

Comment: @avp, если заменить функциональный выпендрёж с `transform` на нормальный цикл, то получится отличный вариант...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, imho он где-то есть в ваших вариантах

Comment: @Dmitry Sokolov - Ваш вариант по какой то причине не работает. `data` заполнен лишь с 1 элементом и его значение пустое

Comment: @avp, не совсем... про `sregex_iterator` я, откровенно говоря, не знал...

Comment: @WithoutExperience, регулярка немного неправильная. должно быть как-то так: `([^:]+):\s*([^\n]+)\n`... только проверь, что в исходниках конец строки нормальный, иначе копипастой не заработает...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Теперь работает :)

Comment: @WithoutExperience, проверялось MSVC 14.26. на остальных компиляторах, возможно, надо флаги добавить.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov Проблема была в `regex`-e

Comment: @WithoutExperience, не совсем - `$` должен сопоставляться с концом строки `\r?\n`, но видимо флаги по-умолчанию в `regex` у разных компиляторов разные.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov, возможно. Для интереса, проверю на виртуалке. А так, запускал на [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/clion/) под Linux.

Comment: @WithoutExperience, в большинстве реализаций регулярок `^` и `$` матчат по умолчанию только начало/конец всего ввода, если явно не указано, что выражение многострочное (*multiline*)... стандарт плюсов вроде как требует соблюдения синтаксиса регулярок ECMAScript, что должно было бы требовать также не сопоставлять `^` и `$` концам строк по умолчанию, так что по идее msvc тут не прав... в с++17 добавили флаг `std::regex_constants::multiline`, дабы разрешить это, но похоже ни libstdc++, ни msvc не стали его реализовывать и оставили всё «по-старому»...

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

const std::string CpuInfo =
  "Architecture:        x86_64\n"
  "CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit\n"
  "Byte Order:          Little Endian\n"
  "Address sizes:       43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual\n"
  "CPU(s):              12\n"
  "On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11\n"
  "Thread(s) per core:  2\n"
  "Core(s) per socket:  6\n"
  "Socket(s):           1\n"
  "NUMA node(s):        1\n"
  "Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD\n"
  "CPU family:          23\n"
  "Model:               1\n"
  "Model name:          AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor\n"
  "Stepping:            1\n"
  "CPU MHz:             2482.474\n"
  "CPU max MHz:         3200.0000\n"
  "CPU min MHz:         1550.0000\n"
  "BogoMIPS:            6387.25\n"
  "Virtualization:      AMD-V\n"
  "L1d cache:           32K\n"
  "L1i cache:           64K\n"
  "L2 cache:            512K\n"
  "L3 cache:            8192K\n"
  "NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11";

int main() {
  std::regex reg_ex("CPU MHz:\\s+([^\\n]+)\\n?");
  std::smatch reg_match;
  std::string result = (std::regex_search(CpuInfo, reg_match, reg_ex)) ? 
    reg_match[1] : std::string("Not found!"); 
  std::cout << "CPU MHz: " << result << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Найдет и выведет: `CPU MHz: 2482.474`

[Вот тут онлайн пример](https://ideone.com/ZOeERy).

**EDIT**: Регулярку поправил, чтобы захватывались значения с пробелами, типа *AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor*.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов много. Вот несколько, практичных решение, которые можно использовать в тех или иных случаях:

- Построчный парсинг потоком. По сути всё как и в вопросе, но читать текст не словами, а строками. Это упрощает логику:

  ```
  void foo() {
    std::istringstream stream(cpuInfo);
    std::string line;

    while (stream.getline(line)) {
      if (line.rfind("CPU MHz:", 0) == 0) { // сравнение наяала строки
        double mhz = getValue<double>(line.c_str() + sizeof ("CPU MHz:") -1);

         // do something
      } else if (line.rfind("Vendor ID:", 0) == 0) {
        std::string vendor = getValue<std::string>(line.c_str() + sizeof ("CPU MHz:") -1);
        // do something else

      }
    }
  // ...
  }

  template<typename T> T getValue(const char *str) {
    T rv;
    std::strstream valueStream(str);
    rv << valueStream;

    if(valueStream.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("parse failed");

    return rv;
  }

  template<std::string> std::string getValue(const char *str) {
    return trim(str); // Обрезать пробелы.
  }
  ```
- Если нужно достать конкретное значение, то можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением:

  ```
  std::regex re("CPU MHz:\\s*(\\S+)\\s*\n");
  std::smatch re_match;
  if (std::regex_search (CpuInfo, re_match, re)) {
    double mhz = getValue<double>(re_match[1]); 
  } else {
    throw std::runtime_error("parse failed");
  }
  ```
- Или просто найти его вручную:

  ```
  size_t mhzPos = cpuInfo.find("CPU MHz:");
  if (n != std::string::npos)) {
    mhzPos += sizeof("CPU MHz:");
    double mhz = getValue<double>(cpuInfo.c_str() + mhzPos);
         // do something
  } else {
    throw std::runtime_error("parse failed");
  }
  ```
- Само собой, регулярками можно парсить и построчно:

  ```
  std::istringstream stream(cpuInfo);
  std::string line;

  while (stream.getline(line)) {
    std::smatch re_match;
    if (std::regex_search (line,std::regex("CPU MHz:\\s*(\\S+)\\s*"), re_match)) {
      double mhz = getValue<double>(re_match[1]);
         // do something
    } else if (std::regex_search (line,std::regex("Vendor ID:\\s*(.*\\S)\\s*"), re_match)) {
       std::string vendor = getValue<std::string>(line.c_str() + sizeof ("CPU MHz:") -1);
      // do something else
    }
  }
  ```

  Замечание: здесь нужно убедится, что компилятор додумается не перекомпилировать регулярные выражения на каждой итерации. В противном случае это может вызвать значительны оверхед.
- Если нужно распарсить все или почти все значения, то т.к. текст представляет собой формат вида ключ-значение, то довольно естественным будет создать промежуточный словарь:

  ```
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> cpuInfoHash;
  std::istringstream stream(cpuInfo);
  std::string line;

  while (stream.getline(line)) {
    size_t sepPos = line.find(':');
    if (n != std::string::npos)) {
      std::string key = line.substr(0, sepPos);
      std::string val = trim(line.substr(sepPos+1));
      cpuInfoHash.emplace(key, value);
    }
  }

  double mhz = getValue<double>(cpuInfoHash.at("CPU MHz"));
  std::string vendor = cpuInfoHashat.at("Vendor ID");
  // ^ осторожно, at() кидается исключениями
  ```

---

#### Общие замечания

- Этот списов вариантов не исчерпывающий. Это базовые варианты, пришедшие на ум.
- Использование потоков для парсинга числовых значений из строки — хорошая практика т.к. позволяет использовать шаблоны, добится универсальности при обработке пробелов и т.п., а также позволяет обрабатывать ошибки.
- Набор функций по обработке строк в C++ из коробки, объективно говоря, довольно ущербный. Так что, если используешь только stl, то не стоит чураться писать свои велосипеды для элементарных операций вроде `trim()`.
- В C++17 операции с голыми сишными строками выше стоит обернуть в `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу оставить комментарий, поэтому напишу в ответы:

@bbdd, если скорость действительно важна и решение с регулярными выражениями подходит, то нужно помнить, что `std::regex` работает очень и очень медленно по сравнению с [`re2`](https://github.com/google/re2) или же библиотекой от [`boost`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Откровенно говоря, для разбора /proc/cpuinfo регулярки вообще не нужны