# Разное поведение regex в Win и Unix

Tags: c++, windows, регулярные-выражения, unix

Пишу на с++ обработку с помощью std::regex и заметил разное поведение в windows и unix якоря конца строки $.

В качестве Unix подсистема Ubuntu 20.04 LTS на WSL2.

Компилятор g++ : `g++ main.cpp -o test`

Простой пример.

Код:

```
if (file.is_open())
{
    getline(file, s);
}
file.close();

std::regex r(R"(SOME$)");
const vector<string> syntax_error{
        sregex_token_iterator{s.cbegin(), s.cend(), r, -1},
        sregex_token_iterator{}
};

for (auto error : syntax_error)
{
    cout << error << endl;
}
```

Входной файл:

```
SOME
/
```

Вывод в unix:

```
SOME
```

Вывод в Windows(visual studio) пустой, т.е корректный.

Пробовал менять $ на \n, результат тот же. Как добиться одинакового поведения?

Файл input.txt тот же.

Comment: Какой текст в вашем файле?

Comment: К вопросу не относится, но в реализации с++ от msvc необычно интерпретируется `$` для многостр. текстов: [см. комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170476/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1&lq=1#comments-1170511)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне удалось воспроизвести эту "ошибку". Как я и думал, проблема не в регулярках, с ними все в порядке. Проблема именно в том, что

> Файл input.txt тот же.

да да, что он именно физически один и тот же.

Дело в том, что в Linux и windows приняты разные символы перевода строк. В Linux это `0x0A`, в Windows это `Ox0D 0x0A`. И когда в Linux читается строка, то там на самом деле читается чуточку больше - там получается `SOME\0x0D` (то есть, ещё один байт). В этом легко убедится, если распечатать длину прочитанной строки. А раз строки разные, то и результат очевидно может быть разным.

Что делать? например, попробовать отрезать этот символ в конце

```
if (s.back() == 13) s.pop_back();
```

или просто использовать нативные переводы строк в файле.